# Calculating differential equation involving exponential function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Given a differential equation

$R'(t)=-e^{-vR(t)}-t+1$

how would one find R(t)?

What I tried: Without trying any special solving methods, I tried to integrate both sides so that I get $R(t)=\frac{-e^{-vR(t)}}{-vR'(t)}-\frac{t^2}{2}+t+c$.

I thought maybe if I insert R'(t) again I can get a nice equation, but I'm stuck on this part. WolframAlpha says that the part $\frac{-t^2}{2}+t$ is correct but the integral of the exponential function doesn't really work out.

Comment: When checking your work, note that the derivative of $\frac{-e^{v R(t)}}{-v R'(t)}$ is **not** $-e^{-v R(t)}$... Do you see why?

Comment: Ah, I see because R' uses t as an input. But can you give me a hint on how to solve this integral?

Comment: Can anybody give me a hint on how to solve this differential equation?

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is
$$R'(t)=-e^{-vR(t)}-t+1,$$
taking $\ln w=-vR$ wich implies $\frac{w'}{w}=-vR'$, we get
$$w'=-vw(-w-t+1).$$
This is a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) that can be solved transforming to a linear equation.